# Blaschke Product

Tags: complex-analysis

I really need to understand Blaschke product very well. I have learned the basic material from Garnett's books on Bounded analytic functions and from Rudin's Real and complex analysis. But I'm looking for a more specialized material on Blaschke product which I'm not able to find. Please suggest articles or books on the same.

Comment: So, what did you learn about it?

Comment: I learned about the Blaschke sequence, given a Blaschke sequence how to construct the infinite Blaschke Product, the existence of radial limit almost everywhere. I mean the section in Rudin's chapter 15 about Blaschke Product.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the boundary behaviour of Blaschke products with prescribed zeros, a systematic treatment.\

Comment: See these books [(I)](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-5341-3/page/1), [(II)](http://books.google.ca/books/about/The_Theory_of_Hp_Spaces_and_the_Boundary.html?id=ScsgSQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Could you please write out the titles and authors of these books? The first link is broke.